# Как сделать равные стороны контейнера с элементом, если элемент не равен квадрату?

Tags: html, css

Для наглядности набросал пример. На примере видим, что высота иконки больше, чем ее ширина. Если вокруг иконки создать контейнер (выделил серым цветом), то контейнер аналогично не будет равен квадрату.

Вопрос: как сделать контейнер квадратным?
Интересует больше css/html вариант реализации...

Можно конечно задать руками значение width: 100px; (сейчас его высота), но хотелось бы на автомате получать квадрат.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.icon_container {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.icon {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-/rXc/GQVaYpyDdyxK+ecHPVYJSN9bmVFBvjA/9eOB+pb3F2w2N6fc5qB9Ew5yIns" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="icon_container">
  <i class="icon fab fa-angellist"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Если задать элементу, любой `width`  и `padding-bottom: 100%`, то получится квадратный блок.

Comment: @Dantessss покажите пример плиз...

Comment: у меня нет четкого примера под твой код, но я имел ввиду вот [это](https://jsfiddle.net/awfq5sdx/1/)

Comment: @Dantessss опробовал, в моем случае решение не работает...